# How use progress bar without Timer using in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, progress

Hello every one how i use  progress bar without Timer using in vb.net i have try but i dont get the solution please help me

Dim i As Integer

```
ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
ProgressBar1.Maximum = 200

For i = 0 To 200
    ProgressBar1.Value = i
    Next
```

End Sub

Comment: What progress do you want to indicate with the progress bar? In the sub that changes the status of that progress, you simply increment the progress bar"s value.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the ProgressBar1?

Comment: If you are simply using this as an animation and not to indicate _actual progress_ then a timer is the best way to go. Fast-running loops like this are not supposed to update the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be indeed working properly. Just make sure you're *executing the code*, for example, on the **Form Load** event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 0 To 200
            ProgressBar1.Value = i
        Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UpdateProgressBar()
    Static v As Integer
    If v < 200 Then
        v += 10 'This could be any number you want to increment by
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Value = v
End Sub
```

Call this at intervals from a long running process.